# Is there such thing as an .rsyncignore file

Tags: rsync, tar

Just like with tar and npm and commands like that, I am looking to use an ignore file like:

```
.myrsyncignore
```

like:

```
rsync -r --exclude='.myrsyncignore'  ./  tmp/foo
```

instead of having to ignore everything at the command line, does such an option exist? it appears not: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders/

Comment: Also, look at the `-F` option in the man page. You can then have a different personalised list of exclusions in any directory by putting them in a `.rsync-filter` file in that directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the option is called `--exclude-from`:

```
rsync --exclude-from=somefile source target
```

You can read about it in the `rsync` manual (`man rsync`), and it's also mentioned in the blog post that you linked to.

Comment: totally missed it in the blogpost thx